# {Switch} and Mod for even/odd amount of entries

Tags: channel-entries, switch

I have a html structure where two entries are grouped into one div, so what I do is this:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="bullets" dynamic="no"}
     {switch='<div class="bullets">|'}
           <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6">
                                ...some content...
           </div>
     {switch='|</div>'}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

This works great as long as I have an even number of entries in the channel. If I have an odd number the closing  is not being added.

I was wondering if I can somehow do something like this:

```
{if total_results mod 2 != 0}
   </div>
{/if}
```

to make sure I have a closing tag if I have an odd number of entries.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I solved it myself using the MX Calculator[1] Plugin and adding this here before the end of the loop:  
  
    {!-- add a div if the number of entries is odd --}
       {if  "{count}" == "{total_results}"}
          {if "{exp:mx_calc expression='mod({total_results},2)'}" != "0"}
              </div>
          {/if}
    {/if}

Answer (score 4):

Well, if you want a modulus operator, use a [modulus operator](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/conditionals.html#modulus-operator)!

```
{if total_results % 2 != 0}
   </div>
{/if}
```

Maybe you can find it easier this way:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="bullets" dynamic="no"}
     {if count = 1 OR count % 2 == 1}
     <div class="bullets">
     {/if}
           <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6">
                                ...some content...
           </div>
     {if count == total_results OR count % 2 == 0}
     </div>
     {/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```